# Concatenation preprocessing:

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

This line :

```
#define hash_hash # ## #
```

will produce `##` but isn't that Undefined Behavior based on :

> If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is
>   undefined.

**EDIT:**

> In other words, expanding hash_hash produces a **new token**, consisting
>   of two adjacent sharp signs, **but this new token is not the ##
>   operator**.

The categories of preprocessing tokens are:

> Preprocessing tokens fall into five broad classes: identifiers,
>   preprocessing numbers, string literals, punctuators, and other

Is `##` new token falls in **other** category **if there is no UB**.

*Note: please take your times to read the question and answer according to it or even before downvoting it.*

Comment: What do you think undefined behaviour means? It means it can do anything.

Answer (score 7):

That is an example from the standard. `##` *is* a valid preprocessing token. It is the token which forms the concatenation operator, as used right there. It simply has no meaning in the C grammar (after preprocessing). But it appears in the list of punctuation tokens, equally as `*` or `++`.

Since no grammar rule will match it, the inevitable result is a syntax error which will be diagnosed. *Unless*, it is passed to another macro which stringizes or ignores it.

```
#define IGNORE(X)
#define STRINGIZE_LIT(X) #X
#define STRINGIZE(X) STRINGIZE_LIT(X)

IGNORE( hash_hash ) // OK, token is not passed to semantic analysis.
printf( STRINGIZE( hash_hash ) ); // OK, same as printf( "##" );
```

Comment: You did not answer my question I know it is concatenation used there.

Comment: @Sabrina You've edited the question now, but the answer remains the same. Yes, the token is in the "other" category.